# Anybody have an alternative method?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm rather new, so if this seems a bit silly I apologize, but is there any actual way of subtracting in multiples of 2 throughout array positions?

```
 let numberOne = Math.floor(Math.random() * (15 - 5) + 5),
     numberTwo = 100,
     arrayOne = [],
     arrayTwo = [];
    while (numberTwo > 0){
    numberTwo = numberTwo - numberOne
      arrayOne.push(numberTwo)
    }
    arrayTwo.push(arrayOne[0] - arrayOne[1])
    arrayTwo.push(arrayOne[2] - arrayOne[3])
    console.log(arrayTwo);
```

Comment: please add some examples with numbers. btw, integer values need no `floor`/`ceil`.

Comment: Alright, I made a revision below as an answer.

Comment: please add it to the question. answers should address the problem and ahve a solution or the way to one, not a further problem description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are subtracting values from an array with deltas of the random number.

The result of the difference of two following values is always exact the random value.

```js
let min = 5,
    max = 15,
    numberOne = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min),
    numberTwo = 100,
    arrayOne = [],
    arrayTwo = [];

while (numberTwo > 0) {
    numberTwo -= numberOne;
    arrayOne.push(numberTwo);
}

console.log(numberOne);   // random value
console.log(...arrayOne); // all deltas

arrayTwo.push(arrayOne[0] - arrayOne[1]);
arrayTwo.push(arrayOne[2] - arrayOne[3]);

console.log(arrayTwo);
```